# coding on task monitor, using array rather than database?

Tags: php, arrays

I am planning to code a project status monitor, the idea in matrix is like below

```
        require1     require2       require3
task1   1   2   0
task2   1   0   2
task3   0   1   1
task4   1   0   0
```

eg. when there is a new project, task1,2,3... should be included, and the requirement 1,2,3... is need to complete for the correspondent task, the letter 0,1,2 to represent that if 1 record in require1 and 2 in require2 and 0 in require3 means the task1 is completed.

my question is that, should I put this matrix into a database then using it to join the record table (concerning the speed if in mass of record),  or can I use an array to implement in simply way ?

Please help to suggest and let me know how to use array!

Thank you.

Comment: You can use a multidimensional array is that's what you're looking for: `$arr = array(); $arr[0][] = 1;` This is a simple two dimensional array and you can add more dimensions if you want but it might get a little unorganized if you have a 3+ dimensional array of pure numbers. Is that along the lines of what you were asking?

Comment: Here's the manual on using arrays if you choose to go this way:   http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Meh just throw it at SQLite